# Why progressEvent.total returning -1 in phonegap

Tags: cordova

Im trying to download multiple files. File is downloading fine in my device. But progressEvent giving some weird results. for all case progressEvent.total returning -1. although progressEvent.loaded value always changing . 
How to fix it.

```
function downloadFile(remoteUrl, localPath) {
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
            var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
            //statusDom.innerHTML = perc + "% loaded...";
            statusDom.innerHTML = progressEvent.loaded + " - " + progressEvent.total;
        } else {
            if(statusDom.innerHTML == "") {
                statusDom.innerHTML = "Loading";
            } else {
                statusDom.innerHTML += ".";
            }
        }
    };

    fileTransfer.download(encodeURI(remoteUrl), localPath, function(e) {}, fail);
}
```

Comment: could you please try this code `var perc = Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);`

Comment: @amorbytes i did try this one. and its returning something like -1000%
because progressEvent.total giving -1. so whatever loaded is showing negative output :(

Comment: Is it happening like that for multiple files download or the same when you download single file?

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela well its happening for multiple download. and weird thing is some times progressEvent.total showing some value. otherwise just -1.

Comment: I would guess that if it works for single file download and not for multiple it has some problems with collecting total of all files. It could be a bug though:)

Comment: As I'm checking the the possibility in downloading a file in Android I've found that URLConnection's getConntetLength method returns the value of field "Content-Length" from response header or -1 if field not available - maybe here is similar?